# Start and Stop an external app from my own app in Android

Tags: android, kill-process

My app starts others apps (upon user request) using this simple code:

```
Intent LaunchApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("the.external.app.package");                 
startActivity( LaunchApp );
```

Is there a way to finish or close that app?

I have tried with ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses() and with android.os.Process.sendSignal(pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL) but no success.

The idea is to do something like this:
If the app connects to the car bluetooth then it starts the music player automatically. Once the bluetooth is disconnected it should close the music player.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the permissions to kill to your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did "android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"

Answer (score 0):

You can close activity without killing process.

1. Use `startActivityForResult()` instead `startActivity()`

   ```
   startActivityForResult( LaunchApp, 100 );// reques code = 100
   ```
2. Close activity by request code when you need that

   ```
   finishActivity( 100 );
   ```

Comment: Sorry, the external app doesn't get closed